# Error indicated at .html and pointed at .js

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am new to javascrpting and this is a completely newbie question.

I have a `index.html` file that looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>The d3 test</title>
<style>
.chart {

}

.main text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;  
}

.axis line, .axis path {
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
    stroke: black;
    fill: none;
}

circle {
    fill: steelblue;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.v2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class='content'>
      <!-- /the chart goes here -->
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="scatter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that `scatter.js` here is a javascript to create a `d3.js` plot.

This code won't work and when I try to inspect for errors using chrome and `Ctrl+Shift+J` I get this error:
[image]

What is this error and why did the browser confuse the `.html` and the `.js`?

Comment: What http server are you using?

Comment: I am using [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

Comment: Fetch the scatter.js with curl and the -i flag and post the results. Also, please post the url paths (ie /static/scatter.js, /widgets/index.htm etc)

Comment: @Craneum `scatter.js` and `index.html`are in the same directory. I didn't understand  this request 'Fetch the scatter.js with curl and the -i flag and post the results.'

Comment: If you are on linux/unix/mac go to you command line and type in "curl -i http://localhost/usecases/first_case/scatter.js" or better yet "curl -i http://localhost/usecases/first_case/scatter.js | pbcopy". The second one will copy to clipboard for you.
Also, in case you didn't realize it, the issue is with django, not your web browser

Answer (score 0):

Is scatter.js located on the same folder than index.html?
If not you must indicate the complete path instead of src="scatter.js"

Comment: `scatter.js` and `index.html` are in the same directory. But thank's anyway for your answer

Comment: meaning you have the same error if you put the complete path ? Like "/scatter.js" or even "http:..../scatter.js" ? If yes do you have specific .htaccess ?